# iOS reset float after button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an app that tracks your speed and altitude. How it works is when you press a start button it starts tracking you and when you press stop it stops and when you press reset it clears everything and the start button comes back. How I did this is I have a hidden label that shows the speed and when you press the button it is not hidden and when you press stop it is hidden again and I make another label say the last thing it said. I also have a max speed label that shows the top speed you reached. I did this using a float. I have the same thing happen for the max speed label that when you press reset the label that has the last thing the max speed label says clears and then the max speed label comes back when you press start. The problem I have is the max speed label itself doesn't reset. When I press start again the max speed label will still show what it had the last time. So how do I reset the max speed label float when the button is pressed to reset it?

EDIT

Here is the code that I have used...

to reset the label...

```
maxspeedlabel.text = @"0.00";
```

for the float...

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location speed]*2.236936284];
altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location altitude]*3.2808399];
latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat: %f", location.coordinate.latitude];
longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long: %f", location.coordinate.longitude];
errorlabel.text = @"   ";

  float currentSpeed = [location speed]*2.236936284;
if(currentSpeed - maxSpeed >= 0.01){
    maxSpeed = currentSpeed;
    maxspeedlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", maxSpeed];

}

float currentAltitude = [location altitude]*3.2808399;
if(currentAltitude - maxAltitude >= 0){
    maxAltitude = currentAltitude;
    maxaltitudelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", maxAltitude];
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time start is pressed add `maxspeedlabel.text = @"";` to clear the label and then update with the new one when needed.

Comment: This is probably a good solution. Though I'm guessing for your current solution you want fabs(currentSpeed - maxSpeed) >= 0.1

Comment: this is what i did but all it does it change the text, it doesn't reset it so it can say 0.00 but i won't say anything else unless its higher then the past highest speed

Answer (score 0):

```
currentSpeed - maxSpeed >= 0.01
```

Why this comparison? Should you not use

```
if(currentSpeed=>maxSpeed)
```

and I believe

```
maxSpeed = currentSpeed;
maxspeedlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", maxSpeed];
```

is wrong, I think it should be

```
currentSpeed = maxSpeed;
maxspeedlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", maxSpeed];
```

otherwise you would be *setting your maxSpeed higher*, which would probably be incorrect.

The error might be in the *currentSpeed calculation*, have you checked whether or not it enters the if statement?

Comment: The method works well i just need to know how to reset it. Like i will press the reset button and all that will happen is the text will change to 0.00 but the max speed will still not update until you reach a speed higher then the last max speed. So I need to know how to reset it so it starts at 0 every time

Comment: What is your updated code? Do you already have this:
    maxspeedlabel.text = @"";

Because this wouldn't reset it.
    maxspeedlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", maxSpeed]; 
As I understand now you set the new topspeed, which is no maxspeed. I think there would be no problem with this code.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding, sorry, I meant top speed all along. I have a label that shows the top speed and I want to reset it when I press stop so then after when i press start again i don't have to go over the top speed i made the last time. All it does now is show 0.00 but the top speed is still not reset to 0

Comment: I think you should post your updated code, I can't see whats wrong now.

Comment: Maybe it's similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966317/how-to-reset-a-timer-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to set the float to 0 when I tapped the button...

```
maxSpeed = 0;
```